# .htaccess condition that works on many conditions inside

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to try something like if in .htaccess:

I want to Redictes each `?sp=SOMEWHAT` to diffrent `?p=NNN` (some number)
I have a 100 `?sp=` pages.
And I don't want to work on 100 Rules each page load.
If this another method to solve it, I happy to know.

```
if(RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST ^?sp=}{
    RewriteRule ^?sp=bar ?p=5
    RewriteRule ^?sp=foo ?p=9
    RewriteRule ^?sp=tin ?p=15
}
```

This is no logic between the ?sp= and ?p=

Update: I doesn't have access to server config.

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no other way to achieve this ;)
You could ajust your URL logic to get this to work e.g. append the number to the SOMEWHAT.

Comment: This is no logic between the ?sp= and ?p=

Comment: Well, I meant when you call e.g. index.php?sp=foo_001 you could rewrite this normally in the htaccess to index.php?sp=foo&p=001

Comment: _“And I don't want to work on 100 Rules each page load.”_ – then you might be better off with redirecting every `?sp=…` to the same script, and then have that script look up the number to the corresponding sp value in an array or something, and then redirect to the correct `?p=number` from there.

Comment: @CBroe This is exactly why I want to do.
The question is: How I do it without access to server config though

Comment: Rewriting works in .htaccess files, so you don’t need access to the server configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the RewriteMap directive (*iff you have access to the server configuration, as pointed out in a comment. No idea why they thought that needed to be restricted...*). For example:

```
RewriteMap sp_to_s txt:/path/to/map.txt
RewriteRule ^?sp=(.*) ?p=${sp_to_s:$1|0}
```

(the `0` is the default value if none of the pairs in the map match).

Here's a sample map.txt:

```
bar 5
foo 9
tin 15
```

There are more ways to use the map feature; see the documentation for mod_rewrite for details.

Comment: Requires access to server config though, can not be used inside .htaccess

Comment: I doesn't have access to server config.
This is another method?

Comment: @yonilobo I don't know any other method than just having many rules: `RewriteRule ^?sp=bar ?p=5` `RewriteRule ^?sp=foo ?p=9` and so on. If you need a condition for each of them... tough luck, you'll just have to copy and paste a lot. Sorry. :)

Comment: I can use: RewriteRule (something that work on ?sp=*) - [S=50]
And write after that all the rules